# Should I use C(99) booleans ? ( also c++ booleans in c++ ?)

Tags: c++, c, boolean, c99

I haven't done much c programming but when I do  when I need a false I put 0  when I want true I put 1, (ex. while(1)), in other cases I use things like "while(ptr)" or "if(x)".

Should I try using C99 booleans, should I recommend them to others if I'm helping people new to programming learn c basics(thinking of cs 1?? students)?

I'm pretty sure the Visual Studio compiler supports c99 bools, but do a lot of projects (open source and c apps in industry) compile for c89? If I don't use C bools should I at least do something like #define TRUE 1 #define FALSE 0?

Also what about c++ Booleans (for c++)?

Comment: Visual Studio does not support C99-style `bool` (or `stdbool.h`) when compiling C code - at least through VS 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ there is no reason to not use it. In C, i only use `int` for this task, without any `#define` or something like that. Variable-names like `isDefinition` are clear enough to indicate what's going on, in my opinion.

Of course, there is nothing wrong with defining your own bool or using the ones of `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: There is something wrong with defining your own instead of using the standard header, unless you have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: @Stephen i suspect this good reason would be portability for most :)

Comment: Defining your own bool will leave you with one of the problems bool was introduced to solve. The builtin _Bool (or bool) type ensures any two true boolean values will compare equal to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use the language abstractions when they are available.  When I use an older C compiler I still create some abstraction of a bool.  Using literals in your code is a very poor practice.

Comment: Generally I agree about literals, but in this case `0` is essentially C's way of spelling "false".

Comment: Yeah, I can give 0 a pass since it is also a legit way to represent NULL.

Answer (score 2):

C++ booleans are fine as they are part of the language and are supported by basically any C++ compiler these days.

C99 booleans seem like a good idea but just keep in mind whether the code you write today will ever need to be used in a C89 project...

Comment: And even then it's not difficult to define the right types in a header.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can do better optimization when it knows a variable is boolean. Also when using ints it's easier to introduce bugs when used in a bitwise context, as ints can be inadvertently set to values other than 1

Comment: +1 for bringing this up. However, non-zero is essentially C for "true". Anybody mixing bitwise and boolean operators on purpose deserves what they get. Anybody doing it on accident is yet another sad victim of C's language designers.

Answer (score 1):

Use bool in C++. It has been there for years and every C++ compiler supports it,
Use it in C if your code requires other C99 features.
Don't use it in pre-C99 code, since any non-zero value will be interpreted as true, and using defines may lead to bugs that are hard to track down (some C library functions are documented to return any non-zero int value, and even if it's generally poor practice to write something like

```
if (var==TRUE) { ... }
```

things like this may break, and might even behave differently under different compilers/operating systems.